# Android - App crashes on android phone but not on Android Emulator (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, google-play

I just published an app, that I tested yesterday. The app works perfect on the emulators from Android Studio (except from being slow of course), but the app crashes if doing a specific part on the app (one of the main features).

I tested it this morning on the emulators again, still everything works on my PC.

I checked the code that happens during this crash (Refer below), but can't seem to find anything:

**CalculateActivity**

```
public class CalculateActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView txtBewareTurnoverTime;

    EditText txtPoolSize;
    EditText txtTurnoverTime;
    EditText txtTurnoverRate;

    Button btnCalculate;

    ImageButton imgBtnTurnoverTime, imgBtnTurnoverRate;

    Animation shakeAni;

    RelativeLayout layoutPoolSize, layoutTurnoverTime, layoutTurnoverRate;
    LinearLayout layoutInfoTurnoverRate;
    LinearLayout layoutInfoTurnoverTime;

    boolean infoTurnoverRate = false;
    boolean infoTurnoverTime = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculate);

        FindAllById();
        SetListeners();
    }

    //Finds all views by their ID and applies them to the variables
    private void FindAllById() {
        txtPoolSize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPoolSizeEdit);
        txtTurnoverTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTurnoverTimeEdit);
        txtTurnoverRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTurnoverRateEdit);
        txtBewareTurnoverTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfoTurnoverTime);
        layoutPoolSize = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutPoolSize);
        layoutTurnoverTime = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutTurnoverTime);
        layoutTurnoverRate = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutTurnoverRate);
        imgBtnTurnoverRate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnTurnoverRate);
        imgBtnTurnoverTime = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnTurnoverTime);
        layoutInfoTurnoverRate = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutInfoTurnoverRate);
        layoutInfoTurnoverRate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        layoutInfoTurnoverTime = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutInfoTurnoverTime);
        layoutInfoTurnoverTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    //Set the listeners on the various components
    private void SetListeners(){
        btnCalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateBtnCalcView);
        btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ShakeAnimation();
            }
        });

        imgBtnTurnoverTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!infoTurnoverTime){layoutInfoTurnoverTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); infoTurnoverTime = true;}
                else{layoutInfoTurnoverTime.setVisibility(View.GONE); infoTurnoverTime = false;}
            }
        });

        imgBtnTurnoverRate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!infoTurnoverRate){layoutInfoTurnoverRate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); infoTurnoverRate = true;}
                else{layoutInfoTurnoverRate.setVisibility(View.GONE); infoTurnoverRate = false;}
            }
        });
    }

    //Plays the animation for the correct relative layouts, if any
    private void ShakeAnimation(){

        shakeAni = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CalculateActivity.this, R.anim.shake);
        int switchInt = new AnimationHelper().CalculateAnimationInt(txtPoolSize.getText().toString(), txtTurnoverTime.getText().toString(), txtTurnoverRate.getText().toString());

        switch(switchInt){
            case 1: layoutPoolSize.startAnimation(shakeAni);
                    layoutTurnoverTime.startAnimation(shakeAni);
                    layoutTurnoverRate.startAnimation(shakeAni);
                break;
            case 2: layoutPoolSize.startAnimation(shakeAni);
                    layoutTurnoverTime.startAnimation(shakeAni);
                break;
            case 3: layoutPoolSize.startAnimation(shakeAni);
                    layoutTurnoverRate.startAnimation(shakeAni);
                break;
            case 4: layoutTurnoverTime.startAnimation(shakeAni);
                    layoutTurnoverRate.startAnimation(shakeAni);
                break;
            case 5: layoutPoolSize.startAnimation(shakeAni);
                break;
            case 6: layoutTurnoverTime.startAnimation(shakeAni);
                break;
            case 7: layoutTurnoverRate.startAnimation(shakeAni);
                break;
            case 8: StartResultActivity();
                break;
        }
    }

    //Start the ResultActivity with the given variables
    private void StartResultActivity(){
        Intent i = new Intent().setClass(CalculateActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("poolSize", txtPoolSize.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("turnoverTime", txtTurnoverTime.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("turnoverRate", txtTurnoverRate.getText().toString());
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**ResultActivity**

```
public class ResultActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView resultPumpRequirement;
    TextView resultFilterAreaRequirement;
    TextView resultMinimumDiameterFilter;

    Button btnFilters;
    Button btnPumps;

    String poolSize;
    String turnoverTime;
    String turnoverRate;

    int pumpRequirement;
    double filterAreaRequiment;
    int minimumDiameterFilter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);


        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if(intent != null) {
            poolSize = intent.getStringExtra("poolSize");
            turnoverTime = intent.getStringExtra("turnoverTime");
            turnoverRate = intent.getStringExtra("turnoverRate");

            Calculate();
            SetText();
            SetListeners();
        }
    }

    //Set the listeners on the various components
    private void SetListeners() {
        btnFilters = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFilters);
        btnFilters.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(new URLHelper().CreateFilterURL(minimumDiameterFilter))));
            }
        });

        btnPumps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPumps);
        btnPumps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(new URLHelper().CreatePumpURL(pumpRequirement))));
            }
        });
    }


    //Calculates the variables using the custom Calculate helper class (CalculateResult)
    private void Calculate(){
        CalculateHelper calcHelper = new CalculateHelper(poolSize, turnoverTime, turnoverRate);

        pumpRequirement = calcHelper.CalculatePumpRequirement();
        filterAreaRequiment = calcHelper.CalculateFilterAreaRequirement();
        minimumDiameterFilter = calcHelper.CalculateMinimumDiameterFilter();
    }

    //Applies everything to the view "activity_result" after being calculated
    private void SetText(){

        resultPumpRequirement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultPumpRequirement);
        resultPumpRequirement.setText(Html.fromHtml(pumpRequirement + " m<sup><small>3</small></sup> per time"));

        resultFilterAreaRequirement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultFilterAreaRequirement);
        resultFilterAreaRequirement.setText(Html.fromHtml(filterAreaRequiment + " m<sup><small>2</small></sup>"));

        resultMinimumDiameterFilter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultMinimumDiameterFilter);
        resultMinimumDiameterFilter.setText(minimumDiameterFilter + "mm");
    }
}
```

These are the two classes actually doing anything during this crash. I can't seem to find **ANY** flaws, and I was hoping that some of you would be able to spot anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: @Raghunandan It crashes on an actual phone that dowlaoded this app from Google Play, not on my PC. Can I get a stacktrace from a phone?

Comment: if you have any mechanism for the same such as google crash analytics or crashlytics form fabric

Comment: Connect the Phone to computer and in Eclipse set filter to display only the logs of this application which you say crashes in phone. When the app crashes, it logs the exception details in the logcat window (or equivalent if you are using Android studio) . In this way you can get the exception details. Please post the exception details here so we can help.

Comment: The problem is that the phone I'm using can't connect to the PC, I've tested it on a friends phone. I'm currently in the process of acquiring a phone.

Comment: Alright I found the error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.welldana.christian.welldanaapp/com.welldana.christian.welldanaapp.GUI.ResultActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "0,64"`

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

As the language `Locale` was set to danish on the phone, the program replaced `.` with `,` which caused the error.

I simply replaced my code with the following:

```
//Calculates the minimum optimal filter area requirement
public double CalculateFilterAreaRequirement(){
    CalculateTurnoverPerHour();
    double tmp = turnoverPerHour/turnoverRate;
    filterAreaRequirement = Math.floor(tmp * 100) / 100;
    return filterAreaRequirement;
}
```